# ClearCase activity comments not showing up

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

Does anybody know why comments that were applied to a chact (or any other command on an activity) don't show up when I do lshistory? Is this the wrong command to get comments?

I just want to see the comments applied to an activity. For instance, I tried the following:

```
ct chactivity -c "My new comment" -headline "Test headline" activity:...
```

The headline changed just fine on the activity, but when I do the following:

```
ct lshistory -l activity:...
```

I only ever see one event - the "create activity" event

Am I looking in the wrong place for comments? Or is it possible this kind of commenting is turned off in ClearCase somehow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in [`event_ccase` CC7.x](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/events_ccase.htm) (even [in 8.x](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8m0r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/events_ccase.htm&resultof=%2522%2565%2576%2565%256e%2574%2573%255f%2563%2563%2561%2573%2565%2522%2520)), you will see that `cleartool chact` itself does not generate a minor event.

However, changing the comment of any object does.

> When you supply comments to a ClearCase command, your comment becomes part of an event record.
>
> Some `cleartool` commands create a comment even if you do not provide one.
> These generated comments describe the operation in general terms, such as “modify metadata” or “create directory element.”
> User comments, if any, are appended to generated comments.

It is, as you have noted, a "minor" event, visible with [`cleartool lshistory -minor`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8m0r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lshistory.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have to specify -minor in the lshistory and then all of the events (and their associated comments) show up.